# How to apply condiation in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
 if ((newFile.type != "image/gif" ) || (newFile.type !=="image/jpg") || (newFile.type !=="image/png") (newFile.type !=="image/jpeg")) 
{ setFileErr(true) }

    else if((newFile.type == "image/gif") || (newFile.type === "image/jpg") || (newFile.type === "image/png") || (newFile.type === "image/jpeg")) 
{ setFileErr(false) }
```

I have used conditions like this. Only first condition newFile.type == "image/gif" is applying. Others are not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: Unrelated, but once you've determined you have a valid file type you know the only other possibility is an invalid type. You have a problem negate your test for an invalid type should be checking if it's not gif *and* it's not jpg *and* etc.

Comment: I want to check if the file type is any of these or not. Can you show me what is the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to manage this.

```
const allowedTypes = ["image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg"]
if (allowedTypes.includes(newFile.type)) {
  setFileErr(false)
} else {
  setFileErr(true)
}
```

Comment: Could even just change this to `setFileErr(!allowedTypes.includes(newFile.type))`

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((newFile.type != "image/gif" ) || (newFile.type !=="image/jpg") || (newFile.type !=="image/png")  (newFile.type !=="image/jpeg")) 
{ setFileErr(true) }
```

You just miss a || at the last condition `(newFile.type !=="image/png") || (newFile.type !=="image/jpeg"))` and make sure newFile.type is a string so `===` can work (`===` is can be equal if only both of value is the same type).

Answer (score -1):

You're using double equal signs for the correct condition, for the others you're using triple equal signs, which have a different meaning. Change them to `==` and `!=` and your code should work.

Comment: If "type" is a string the strictness doesn't matter. Look more closely at the logic.